# I wanted to show Usage and disclaimer so I wrote the below code but my app hangs

Tags: android

What is wrong with the below code?

```
public void UsageNDisclaimer(View view) {

    //Partha - show the usage and disclaimer here

    // Dialog dialog = new Dialog(contex);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    TextView txt = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textbox);
    txt.setText(getString(R.string.message));
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs)

As you can see, the android framework provide an easy way to implement dialogs (dialog fragments, but most likely for you, alert dialogs).

I guess from your example, that you only want a "yes" dialog, this is informative, no action are required. 
So you can do:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

builder.setMessage(R.string.message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Dont forget dialog.show() when needed.